# what does decouple do and what does import config do?

Tags: python

I saw this interesting idea from Kalle Hallden's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imN-vhi5ZWQ&t=82s). It is about alerting you when someone's IP connects to the network. I thought it would be really interesting to copy the code and use it, however I am not really good in python and I have some trouble.

On the third line it is `from decouple import config` when I put it in my code `decouple` and `config` is underlined red. I understand that is an error of some sort but I do not know how to resolve it. I hope someone here could help me. Thank you.

the code

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from decouple import config

IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
IP_DEVICE = config('IP_DEVICE')

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", IP_NETWORK],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  #the real code does filtering here
  connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3]

  if connected_ip == IP_DEVICE:
      subprocess.Popen(["say", "Linnea just connected to the network"])
```

Comment: I guess you need to install the [`python-decouple`](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) library.

Comment: It sounds like the error is coming from your linter, not Python. What's the error exactly? Have you even tried running the script? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named decouple. does that mean i need to manually install decouple? as i said i am new

Comment: @Jeez123 Yes, it means you have to install it. Please look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)  for how to install modules. If you get stuck on anything there, try to open up a new question regarding that specifically.

Comment: i actually installed it afterwards and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**pip install python-decouple**

this command will install the decouple library and will allow you to use it further.